# Using main jar methods from dynamically loaded jar

Tags: java, bukkit

I am making a module for a plugin. The main application loads the plugin, which then loads the modules for my plugin (Main Application --Loads Plugins--> My Plugin --Loads Modules--> My Module).

I have a jar (we'll call it dynamicJar) that I am loading dynamically into my plugin. The issue I have is when I want to use methods and classes from my plugin in dynamicJar I get a NoClassDefFound error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: me/venom/crates/objects/crates/Crate
at me.venom.csgo.CSGOCrate.runCSGO(CSGOCrate.java:135) ~[CSGOCrates.jar:?]
at me.venom.crates.CSGOHelper.runCSGO(CSGOHelper.java:58) ~[?:?]
at me.venom.crates.PListener.onChestInteract(PListener.java:194) ~[?:?]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.7.0_75]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) ~[?:1.7.0_75]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.7.0_75]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) ~[?:1.7.0_75]
at org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPluginLoader$1.execute(JavaPluginLoader.java:306) ~[spigot-1.9.jar:git-Spigot-1480adb-8b61cc5]
... 17 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: me.venom.crates.objects.crates.Crate
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366) ~[?:1.7.0_75]
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355) ~[?:1.7.0_75]
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[?:1.7.0_75]
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354) ~[?:1.7.0_75]
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425) ~[?:1.7.0_75]
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308) ~[?:1.7.0_75]
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358) ~[?:1.7.0_75]
at me.venom.csgo.CSGOCrate.runCSGO(CSGOCrate.java:135) ~[CSGOCrates.jar:?]
at me.venom.crates.CSGOHelper.runCSGO(CSGOHelper.java:58) ~[?:?]
at me.venom.crates.PListener.onChestInteract(PListener.java:194) ~[?:?]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.7.0_75]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) ~[?:1.7.0_75]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.7.0_75]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) ~[?:1.7.0_75]
at org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPluginLoader$1.execute(JavaPluginLoader.java:306) ~[spigot-1.9.jar:git-Spigot-1480adb-8b61cc5]
... 17 more
```

The issue is that I CAN run methods from the Main Application inside of the dynamicJar, but I can't use the methods from the plugin inside of the dynamicJar.

TL;DR: Using classes that are from the plugin jar throws a ClassNotFoundException and NoClassDefFoundError when they are used from a dynamically loaded jar.

**EDIT:**

Here is the code I am using to load the jars into my class path.

```
    Method method = URLClassLoader.class.getDeclaredMethod("addURL", new Class[]{URL.class});
    method.setAccessible(true);
    method.invoke(ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader(), new Object[]{file.toURI().toURL()});
```

Comment: That's smell like a ClassLoader issue, you will need to provide your code otherwise it will be hard to help

Comment: @NicolasFilotto Edited the main post with the code

Comment: You define your plugins and your modules using the system ClassLoader?

Comment: @NicolasFilotto Should I be doing it a different way? That's the way I've seen it been done before.

Comment: I would personally create my own ClassLoader implementation to avoid such hacky approach and to be able to manage the full lifecycle of my classes, because here how will you unload the classes of a module? Anyway that's not the point here, I just wanted to know how many ClassLoaders are involved in your program

Comment: @NicolasFilotto Okay. I can make my own ClassLoader but I'm still not sure how I would get the methods from my plugin (not the module) into the module.

Comment: Could you please provide the code of JavaPluginLoader?

Comment: @NicolasFilotto I can't, as that's part of the API I'm using to code.

Comment: you mean that it's private ?

Comment: @NicolasFilotto Yes. I'm wondering why adding a jar to my classpath isn't just like making new classes and putting the code into there? As in, it should be able to use all the things my main jar should be able to use.

Comment: You need to show the code allowing you to load a plugin and a module, and if applicable how you load the class dynamically, everything that could be the potential cause where you dynamically load or call something otherwise it will be blind guesses

Comment: @NicolasFilotto I found the source for the Main Application plugin loaders, which is here: https://hub.spigotmc.org/stash/projects/SPIGOT/repos/bukkit/browse/src/main/java/org/bukkit/plugin/java

Comment: @NicolasFilotto I've gotten everything down to a simple ClassLoader of my plugin (not the module). How could I take something like Class<Main> and change it to Main with all its methods?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue by loading the classes into the class loader of the plugin, instead of it's own class loader or the System class loader. Works flawlessly now.

Comment: Happy to know that you could find the answer by yourself